Getting number of performance cores and efficiency cores of MacBook Pro in Terminal
The number of performance and efficiency cores differs wildly between all the variants of the Apple silicon M cpus and Apple usually does not list these even in the technical specs.
Is there a way to get the number of performance cores and efficiency cores and the CPU model from within Terminal?

The following command shows the number of performance cores and efficiency cores and the CPU type:
sysctl -a|egrep 'brand_string|(perflevel.*(physicalcpu:|name))'

On my MacBook Pro M1 this gives the following output:
hw.perflevel0.physicalcpu: 8
hw.perflevel0.name: Performance
hw.perflevel1.physicalcpu: 2
hw.perflevel1.name: Efficiency
machdep.cpu.brand_string: Apple M1 Pro

You can also enter this shorter command to get the caches sizes as well:
sysctl -a|grep perfl

On my MacBook Pro M1 this produces:
hw.perflevel0.physicalcpu: 8
hw.perflevel0.physicalcpu_max: 8
hw.perflevel0.logicalcpu: 8
hw.perflevel0.logicalcpu_max: 8
hw.perflevel0.l1icachesize: 196608 
hw.perflevel0.l1dcachesize: 131072
hw.perflevel0.l2cachesize: 12582912
hw.perflevel0.cpusperl2: 4
hw.perflevel0.name: Performance
hw.perflevel1.physicalcpu: 2
hw.perflevel1.physicalcpu_max: 2
hw.perflevel1.logicalcpu: 2
hw.perflevel1.logicalcpu_max: 2
hw.perflevel1.l1icachesize: 131072
hw.perflevel1.l1dcachesize: 65536
hw.perflevel1.l2cachesize: 4194304
hw.perflevel1.cpusperl2: 2
hw.perflevel1.name: Efficiency
hw.nperflevels: 2

